# Error deploying axis2 service in glassfish

Tags: java, deployment, netbeans, glassfish, apache-axis

I've been trying to deploy an axis2 service using the following:

- Netbeans 6.9.1
- axis2.war (version 1.4.1) and I've also tried (version 1.5.5)
- glassfish 3.1

I create a Java Class Library project and inside this project I create an "Axis2 Service from WSDL". All appears to work correct (Builds without error) but when I try to deploy the service onto the glassfish server I get an error which indicates that there was a problem opening the axis2.war file (Please see below for a console log).

I followed the following tutorials to get this far:

http://netbeans.org/kb/69/websvc/gs-axis.html#axis_options_glassfish
http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/axis2-web-service-support-netb

I'd appreciate any help

Kind Regards,

Justin

```
INFO: [AutoDeploy] Selecting file C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\axis2.war for autodeployment.
WARNING: DPL8004: file open failure; file = file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/axis2.war
WARNING: error in opening zip file --  invalid zip file: file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/axis2.war
WARNING: DPL8004: file open failure; file = file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/axis2.war
WARNING: error in opening zip file --  invalid zip file: file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/axis2.war
WARNING: DPL8004: file open failure; file = file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/axis2.war
WARNING: error in opening zip file --  invalid zip file: file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/axis2.war
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
WARNING: DPL8004: file open failure; file = file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/axis2.war
WARNING: error in opening zip file --  invalid zip file: file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/axis2.war
WARNING: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/axis2/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/axis2/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3066)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
        at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:918)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getURIs(SnifferManagerImpl.java:268)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getApplicableSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:202)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:150)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:604)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:145)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:577)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:395)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:380)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:213)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [axis2] at [/axis2]
INFO: axis2 was successfully deployed in 72,281 milliseconds.
INFO: [AutoDeploy] Successfully autodeployed : C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\axis2.war.
INFO: [AutoDeploy] Selecting file C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\zip1296260213.tmp for autodeployment.
WARNING: [AutoDeploy] Autodeploy failed : C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\zip1296260213.tmp.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stacktrace:

> Illegal character in path at index 16:
>   file:/C:/Program
>   Files/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/axis2/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar

The space in the path name is the problem. Can you switch to a different folder without spaces in path?